# Django url with multiple parameters

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to pass a URL with multiple parameters however, I keep getting NoReverseMatch Error. I have tried printing the parameters and they are printed correctly. Howver, I still get an error.

My view:

```
@login_required
def comment_like(request,guid_url,id):
    data = dict()
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=id)
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        if comment.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            comment.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            comment.likes.add(user)
        data['comment'] = render_to_string('home/posts/comment_like.html',{'comment':comment},request=request)
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

my link:

```
action="{% url 'home:comment-like' post.guid_url comment.id %}"
```

and my url:

```
path('post/<str:guid_url>/comment/<int:id>/like/', views.comment_like, name='comment-like'),
```

The error I get:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'comment-like' with arguments '('', 20)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['home/post/(?P<guid_url>[^/]+)/comment/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/like/$']
```

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

prefix your path with a 'home/'.

Answer (score 0):

NoReverseMatch is a Django exception that is raised when a URL cannot be matched against any string or regular express in your URL configuration. Please check ur url's are correctly matching those or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your template. `post.guid_url` is empty, as suggested by the following part of your error:

> with arguments '('', 20)'

Comment: when I type {{ post.guid_url }} i can see the guid_url being printed.